# Outlook 2007/2010 & GMail Paragraph Spacing Issues in Newsletters

Tags: css, html-email, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I'm getting double spacing in Outlook 2007/2010/2013 and GMail but it looks fine elsewhere. I'm creating a newsletter and I've tried all-sorts: border-collapses, margins, paddings, spans, and still can't get my head around this. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Am I missing something?

Link below - source code too long to paste here. Sorry.

http://pastebin.com/FW3RgYuv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one, all styles must be inline. Most mail clients do not support stylesheets.

You are not building a web page, you're building an email, therefore everything in your HEAD section will be removed, including your embedded stylesheet.

In you code you have `</br>`. This is not a valid tag. Use `<br />`.

**NEVER NEVER** use `!important`. Inline styles already override other styles, plus you can dig yourself into a dead end.

Put your text in a DIV or a P and style that, not the TD. Not all styles are supported by every mail client. [Here's a good list to compare to](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Comment: Anywhere a <br> </br> <br /> has been mentioned in the HTML have been replaced with the P Tags correctly.

Comment: well I've taken the <p> tags and correctly used the <br /> tags as mentioned - just going to test the email now.

Comment: I would advise against using <p>'s within an email. Email clients are inconstant with their styling. I've not had an issue with styles on <td>s (aside from the limited mail client support).

Comment: @samanthasquared I've always used <font> tags exclusively for text styling - Could you elaborate on which clients do/do not support <td> styling? If it is just Lotus "who cares" Notes for example, it might be worth the switch...

Comment: I put all my styles inline on <td>s. I don't use <font> or <p>. I don't use <font> because it works just fine on <td> but with less code since the table has to be there anyway. I've seen <p> randomly add padding/margin/resize text, same with pretty much all semantic tags. You are fortunate if you don't have to be concerned with Lotus Notes, but I find if it works in Outlook '07 & '10, then it is decent in Notes too.

Comment: @samanthasquared Lotus notes only makes up 0.2% of my B2B lists (and less for the older Lotus versions), so those <2 in every thousand need to upgrade imo ;) - I like .png's too much. I'll have to give dropping the font tag a try, although I do like separating structure from content as it makes coding easier.